# Produce random numbers with average in excel

Tags: excel

How to produce random numbers with average in excel with giving total amount. For example I need to have 12 rows result in total amount been giving with random number.

Which is 30000 total amount been giving and I would like to divide into 12 rows with random number. How could I do this?

Comment: `=(randbetween(1,100000)*10000)/12` Try that

Comment: @Mukul215 this only can produce in single row which it divide by 12 in single row. What I needed it total 30000, it can divide into 12 row with average 1900 - 2300 per row value.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Formula for Random Values to get a constant sum]

Above trick can achieve the goal..

Comment: How about if I want the random number in between 1900 - 2300 in each row with total 30000?